# How to add/remove hover event and alternate the newly added table row using dblclick() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Below is my code.

I want to add a hover event and alternating rows to newly added table rows in the second table.

I listen to a double-click event on each table row of the first table, that adds the the table row to the second table. I want to have a hover event and I want to alternate the second table's rows by changing their background colors.

I already alternate the first table rows but if I hover the second table row there is no hover event and no alternating table rows.
I also want to remove the hover in first table on rows that have been double-clicked.

I also want to compute their total values.

But what should I do? sorry I am a beginner using jquery.

This is My Code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Machine Project 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="background:blue" id="list1">List of Course Offerings</h1> <br/>
<table class="tab1" id="t1" border="1" width="1000" height="100">
<thead style="background:silver">
    <tr>
    <th>Course ID </th>
    <th>Course Description</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Tuition Fee</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="t1">
    <tr class="row1">
        <td>001</td>
        <td>Android Programming</td>
        <td>Sat</td>
        <td>10:00AM - 4:00PM</td>
        <td>15,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row2">
        <td>002</td>
        <td>Web Development</td>
        <td>MWF</td>
        <td>5:00PM - 8:00 PM</td>
        <td>10,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row3">
        <td>003</td>
        <td>Desktop Publishing</td>
        <td>TTH</td>
        <td>5:00PM - 8:00PM</td>
        <td>8,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row4">
        <td>004</td>
        <td>C++ Programming</td>
        <td>Sat</td>
        <td>5:00PM - 8:00PM</td>
        <td>12,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row5">
        <td>005</td>
        <td>Java Programming</td>
        <td>MWF</td>
        <td>7:00AM - 1:00PM</td>
        <td>11,000.00</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<h1 style="background:blue" id="list2">List of Selected Courses</h1> <br/>
<table class="tab2" id="t2" border="1" width="1000" >
<thead style="background:gold">
    <tr>
    <th>Course ID </th>
    <th>Course Description</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Tuition Fee</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody >    
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<table class="tab3" id="t3" border="1" width="1000" >
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Total Amount of Tuition Fee</th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
        <th>Php 0.00 </th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list1").click(function(){
        $(".tab1").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $("#list2").click(function(){
        $(".tab2").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $(".tab2 tr:odd").addClass("Odd");
    $("#t1 tr:odd").addClass("Odd");
    $(".tab1 tbody").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
    $('#t2').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
    $(".row1").on('dblclick',function(){
        var cols ="";
        var newRow1=$("<tr class='tlbl'>");
        cols += "<td>001</td><td>Android Programming</td><td>Sat</td><td>10:00AM - 4:00PM</td><td>15,000.00</td>";
        newRow1.append(cols);
        $("table.tab2").append(newRow1);
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
    $(".row2").on('dblclick',function(){
        var cols ="";
        var newRow1=$("<tr class='tlbl'>");
        cols += "<td>002</td><td>Web Development</td><td>MWF</td><td>5:00PM - 8:00 PM</td><td>10,000.00</td>";
        newRow1.append(cols);
        $("table.tab2").append(newRow1);
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
    $(".row3").on('dblclick',function(){
        var cols ="";
        var newRow1=$("<tr class='tlbl'>");
        cols += "<td>003</td><td>Desktop Publishing</td><td>TTH</td><td>5:00PM - 8:00PM</td><td>8,000.00</td>";
        newRow1.append(cols);
        $("table.tab2").append(newRow1);
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
    $(".row4").on('dblclick',function(){
        var cols ="";
        var newRow1=$("<tr class='tlbl'>");
        cols += "<td>004</td><td>C++ Programming</td><td>Sat</td><td>5:00PM - 8:00PM</td><td>12,000.00</td>";
        newRow1.append(cols);
        $("table.tab2").append(newRow1);
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
    $(".row5").on('dblclick',function(){
        var cols ="";
        var newRow1=$("<tr class='tlbl'>");
        cols += "<td>005</td><td>Java Programming</td><td>MWF</td><td>7:00AM - 1:00PM</td><td>11,000.00</td>";
        newRow1.append(cols);
        $("table.tab2").append(newRow1);
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
    $("table.tab2").on('dblclick','.tlbl',function(event){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to achieve. Now it's all a very unclear.

Comment: I want to add hover event and if i add new table rows it will automatically alternates their background colors. there are 2 tables that i created. in first table the events the doubleclick that add table row to another and removing hover events in items in first table, hover event and alternating table row background colors. but if i click the first table rows the hover event not happen in second table and no alternating of background colors in second table also.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your javascript code and css.

You had a `dblclick` event handler for each row seperately, this bloats your code and is not needed. You can simply add a listener to all rows inside the `tbody` of the first table, `clone` the double-clicked row and `append` it to the 2nd table.

As for the alternating rows and hover, you can do this with plain CSS.
Disabling the hover is done with a combination of CSS and JavaScript/jQuery.

To update the total tuition fee, I added a `.tuition-fee` class to all `td` elements holding the tuition fee for that course, and a `span` with class`.total-fee` to indicate where the total fee should be shown. From there on it's easy to get the tuition fee of the added row, the current total and add those 2 together. Then using [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) you can render the result however you like.

Comments are in the code.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ksnqg7fw/3/

**CSS**

```
/**
 * Set alternating rows in both tables
 */
.tab1 tbody tr:nth-child(even),
.tab2 tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

/**
 * Add hover to all rows that don't have the 'disabled' class
 */
.tab1 tbody tr:not(.disabled):hover,
.tab2 tbody tr:not(.disabled):hover {
  background-color: salmon;
}

/**
 * Show the disabled state on disabled rows
 */
.disabled {
  color: grey;
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list1").click(function() {
    $(".tab1").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  $("#list2").click(function() {
    $(".tab2").slideToggle("slow");
  });

  // One listener for all rows inside the first table
  $('.tab1').find('tbody').find('tr').on('dblclick', function() {
    // Create a clone of the double-clicked row
    var $newRow = $(this).clone();
    // Add a 'disabled' CSS class to the double-clicked row
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    // Remove the listener for the double-clicked row, so it can't be added to the selected courses again
    $(this).off('dblclick');
    // Add the copy to the second table
    $('.tab2').find('tbody').append($newRow); 
    // Get the current tuition fee
    // (remove the thousand separators, replace '.' by ',' and parse to number)
    var oldFee = parseFloat($('.total-fee').text().replace(',',''), 10);
    // Get the tuition fee to add
    var feeToAdd = parseFloat($(this).find('.tuition-fee').text().replace(',',''), 10);
    // Use toLocaleString to add the ',' and '.' again, and to add 2 fraction digits add the end
    var newFee = (oldFee + feeToAdd).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
    // Set the new fee
    $('.total-fee').text(newFee);
  });
});
```

Comment: is this the same as if i remove the items in second table and enabled the hover event in first table?what if i calculated their total tuition fee? it is possible to use the val() method?

Comment: I updated my answer with the calculation of the total tuition fee.But what exactly do you mean with your comment?

Comment: Please do take the time to read the code comments, I hope it will help you  understand how the code works and make it a bit clearer how you can use JavaScript and jQuery in an effective way.

Comment: but if i remove the second table rows, how to minus the total tuition feein item that i remove in second table?

Comment: Well, just like I get the total fee, and add the newly added fee to it, you can get the total fee, and subtract the removed fee from it.

Comment: I got it. Thank you again. sorry I am not fluent in english and i'm not practicing my typing. :D

Comment: how about if i remove the appended clone in second table? what would be the syntax? i use the remove but it doesn't work.

Comment: `remove` should work on any element that is inside your DOM. See https://api.jquery.com/remove/ for more information on how to use it. Also, please try to get the grasp of the solution I proposed before actually building further on it. Try to find out why certain things are done and what they do. It will make it easier for you to understand what you're doing.